# Extract text from html page in Go

Tags: html, go

Looking for a way to simply get the text of a web page, preferably without having to resort to a bunch of regular expressions.

Just thought I'd check first in case this kind of thing is already built in, or at least easier to do in Go.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer right now, but https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery might be what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [go-query](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery). This lib can be used like jquery to grep text and doc elements from a html document.

This example is taken from the github page:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "log"
)

func ExampleScrape() {
    doc, err := goquery.NewDocument("http://metalsucks.net")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    doc.Find(".reviews-wrap article .review-rhs").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
        band := s.Find("h3").Text()
        title := s.Find("i").Text()
        fmt.Printf("Review %d: %s - %s\n", i, band, title)
    })
}
func main() {
    ExampleScrape()
}
```